# sequelize find parent table from child

Tags: find, sequelize.js, parent

I would like to find the parent table information of an object.

I have User hasMany Book
where Book has writer and assigned to user id.
Book has type, which is like fantasy, romance, history, scientific fiction... etc

So I want to find out the Book with type Scientific Fiction but not only for that, I also want the writer, which is User.

How can I find the book with its writer where where condition is given for books only? It seems like 'include' in Book.findAll( include: User) is not working; this tells me that include is only working for finding child tables not parent.

Here are some code for user

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.STRING(6), field: 'ID', primaryKey : true }
}
associate: function(models) {
        User.hasMany(models.Book, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
}
```

and book

```
const Book = sequelize.define('Book', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.STRING(6), field: 'ID', primaryKey: true }, // primary key
    userId: { type: DataTypes.STRING(6), field: 'USER_ID', primaryKey: true }
type: { type: DataTypes.STRING(20), field: 'TYPE'

}
```

Book has some more child table and I try to find those additional information in includes, so I guess I really need to find from Book.findAll(...)
Instead of User.findAll(include: Book).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think I was making a mistake.

As soon as I changed

```
userId: { type: DataTypes.STRING(6), field: 'USER_ID', primaryKey: true }
```

to

```
userId: { type: DataTypes.STRING(6), field: 'USER_ID' }
```

include is working for belongsTo; and it finds the parent from child.
It seems like Sequelize has some problem with relation if there is more than one primary key declared in model...

If anyone does think this solves your problem, please share in reply so I can be more sure about it.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, Sequelize's rule is quite simple
Multiple Primary allows for row distinction between complex include models, but only one foreign key is allowed between two tables. If there is more than one, then it would go crazy